# Returning a reference parameter

Tags: c++, reference

Say I have the following code:

```
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string GetPath(const string & aString);

int main()
{
    string dave = "hello";
    string tom = GetPath(dave);

}

string GetPath(const string & aString)
{
    //Do stuff

    //If function fails then return original string
    return aString;

    //or should it be like this
    return string(aString)

}
```

I have a situation where I need to pass a string into a function and if that function fails its task then I would like to simply return the string that was passed in.

My question is that I'm slightly unsure on the behaviour of just returning `aString` as it has been passed by reference. Should this sort of code be avoided, and if so why? I was suprised that I could return it (does it make a copy perhaps?).

To be on the safe side I constructed a new object to be returned `return string(aString)` but again this may be overkill and not necessary.

Any clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: `return aString;` is fine; `return string(aString)` is redundant but will also work fine.

Comment: The function signature states it will retrun a copy, and this exactly what it will do.  Your code as shown will not pose any problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's fine to return `aString` because you **return by value**, so theoretically a copy is created (RVO can kick in, but if it does, it doesn't affect behavior).

> To be on the safe side I constructed a new object to be returned return string(aString) but again this may be overkill and not necessary.

Completely true. Just `return aString;` is fine.

Comment: *Nit-picking*: RVO does affect observable behavior, but not in this case, and not any that one is likely to care about.

Comment: @Robᵩ I know, I was talking about this case because std::string's constructor doesn't affect it.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> return aString;
> ```
>
> My question is that I'm slightly unsure on the behaviour of just returning aString as it has been passed by reference. Should this sort of code be avoided, and if so why?

No, that's just fine.

> I was suprised that I could return it (does it make a copy perhaps?).

Yes, it does make a copy. (and it must make a copy in this case)

> To be on the safe side I constructed a new object to be returned return string(aString) but again this may be overkill and not necessary

Yes, it would be an overkill. The compiler might, or might not optimize it to be exactly the same (through RVO).

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that your main concern is that you're passing `aString` to a function as a reference, and then returning that same reference in `return aString`.
You're not doing that, your function returns by value, so  if necessary will create a copy which is then returned.

I'd guess that you're thinking of references as being an equivalent of pointers, which they're not. Think of them more as an 'alias' of the original object, so if your return is by value, then a copy will be returned. If you returned `const string &` then yes, you would return a reference to the original (hopefully unchanged) object.